# Inspect Element and View Source Code are showing two different things

Tags: html, css, inspect-element

I'm using Inspect Element in Google Chrome to figure out what is controlling the size of the slideshow controller buttons underneath the slideshow of this template website:

http://themefuse.com/demo/html/Medica/index-slider-2.html

When I click Inspect Element over the button "Cardiology" I see a line in the HTML code saying:

`<li style="width: 192px; overflow: hidden;"><a href="#" rel="1" class="">Cardiology</a></li>`

However, when I view source code of the page, no such line exists! This is a problem for me because I would like to edit the size of the button and the text inside it.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

"Source code" is what the browser received from the server. It can be changed by JavaScript; the "Inspect Element" always shows the current shape of the document.

EDIT: Then again, sometimes things are not complicated. Look what I found in the source code:

```
<li>
    <div class="textHolder">
    <h3>Cardiology</h3>
    <p><span><strong><a href="#">Cardiac Rehabilitation Center</a></strong> We helped Glade Inc. design their latest fragrance for household perfumes </span></p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/temp/slider_img_01.jpg" alt="" /> 
</li>
```

It is then further modified by JS.

Comment: If view source is what i recieved from the server , then why do I see [this]( http://i.stack.imgur.com/7fIxN.jpg) html encoding  e.g `&#39` ? the server could have send plain  `'` insted

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Could have but didn't.

Answer (score 1):

This list generated by JS. Check `js/playSlider.js` starting from line #335.

Comment: Thanks... Do you see how I can make one button wider than another?

Comment: Here is width of each list item calculated automatically: common_width/number_of_items. If you have completely different width of texts in this menu, you can, for example, comment line #344: 
//width: (w / (l + 1)) + "px",

and then, in CSS file set padding for list items to fit into space: css/playSlider.css, line #195